# Can't get an AT_TIMESTAMP iterator for Kinesis in boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to get a shard iterator with this piece of Python code (using boto3):

```
  # read data between 10 seconds ago and now
  start_timestamp = int(time.time()) - 10
  client.get_shard_iterator(
    StreamName='stream-name',
    ShardId=shard_id,
    ShardIteratorType='AT_TIMESTAMP',
    Timestamp=start_timestamp,
  )['ShardIterator']
```

But got the following error:

> An error occurred (InvalidArgumentException) when calling the
>   GetShardIterator operation: The timestampInMillis parameter cannot be
>   greater than the currentTimestampInMillis. timestampInMillis:
>   1488245410000, currentTimestampInMillis: 1488245353431

I'm not sure how Kinesis defines `currentTimestampInMillis`. Somehow it is always 66+ seconds later than what I get from `time.time()` in Python. As a result, I have to change `-10` into `-76` to get an iterator.

I googled around but can't seem to find any previous occurrence of this problem.

I also searched around about `currentTimestampInMillis`, hoping to find a way to retrieve its value. But there is no such information.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I had the same problem from java. It seems like you have to know when the last record arrived and have that as timestamp or a previous date. I think the best way is to just handle the error and have it as a "no new records found" for the iterator user code.